# MySQL dbExpress optimising requests. Request speed, so slow

Tags: mysql, performance, delphi

My requests from software are too slow.
I use dbExpress and Delphi Xe4.

My Task is:

Lets see the situation.
We have table called 81-1 ( its need to name like it, there are no 81 tables :D ) 
One user send query in random time. Query type is Insert a new row. 
Our "checker" software scan every 10-50ms ( realy, its need a momenmtly see new information) and if there new record with ``state`=''Free'''` we should imidiently do smth and then change `state` to `NaN`. I Only need very fast "scanner" or "checker" that will check my table for new records.

Here is my code:

```
var
  Qry: TSQLQuery;        i:integer;
begin
Qry := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
try
  Qry.SQLConnection := GSQLConnection;
  Qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM `81-1` WHERE `state`=''Free''';
  Qry.Prepared:=True;
  for i := 1 to 10555 do
  begin

    Qry.Open;
  while not Qry.Eof do
  begin
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('FOUND !111 ');
    Break;
  end;

    form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Req n '+inttostr(i));
    Qry.close;
  end;


  form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('lol')
finally
  Qry.free;
end;
end;
```

This works perfectly. But it's too slow.
If I delete `Qry.close;`, I have a better speed around 100 request per second, before I had like 10 requests per second.
But I don't get real updates this way. Only the first request gets new information, every other just repeats the output of the first.
I want to find new informations in the Database (MySQL) immediately on the software level.

Comment: Why do you open and close the same query 10555 times ?

Comment: To check, is there new information ( rows with `state`=''Free'' ) , or i make smth wrong ?

Comment: Well, to fetch new or recently changed records, I would expect to query by field like `CreatedAt`, or `ChangedAt`. But I'm afraid you to ask if you have these when I see table name `81-1`.

Comment: @OilFrame But why would you want to check if there is new information 10555 times immediately following each other? What are you trying to accomplish (please edit your question)?

Comment: Repeatedly querying your table like that will likely impose a heavy load on your database server and impair its performance for other users.  Does your table have a column which records the date and time a row is added and, if not, would it be possible for one to be added and automatically filled in?  Make sure the table is indexed on that column, btw.  Then, you can restrict your query to select rows added since the last time your code queried it.

Comment: Btw, it would help if you could state in your q details such as the rate at which you expect rows to be added to the table and how quickly you're expecting your code to notice them.

Comment: Oh... I dont understand you guys... Lets see the situation.
We have table called 81-1 ( its need to name like it, there are no 81 tables :D ) 
One user send query in random time. Query type is Insert. 
Our "checker" software scan every 10-50ms ( realy, its need a momenmtly see new information) and if there new record with ``state`=''Free''' ` we should imidiently do smth and then change `state` to `NaN`. I Only need very fast "scanner" or "checker" that will check my table for new records. I dont understand about rows and others, which guys written before.